# Calculo de indicadores de análisis técnico de diferentes temporalidades en python

Tags: python

teniendo un data frame con la cotización de un activo en la temporalidad de 5 minutos, se puede agregar una columna con el calculo de indicadores de otras temporalidades? Por ejemplo agregar una columna con la EMA de 100 períodos correspondiente a la temporalidad de 1 hora del mismo activo para cada una de las velas de 5 minutos.

Hasta ahora lo vengo haciendo pero bastante manual calculando la EMA de 100 en la temporalidad de 1 hora y luego lo llevo al DF de la temporalidad de 5 min para cada hora con el valor que corresponda.
Agradecería si conocen una manera más simple o si existe algún paquete que posea esta funcionalidad ya que con pandas-ta no la estoy encontrando.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.